# Make a specific UPDATE to a SQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

The database above is given.

I have an Employee `Good Employee` and another Employee `Excellent Employee`. `Excellent Employee` runs a Department.

I want to update my database so `Good Employee` works in the Department which is led by `Excellent Employee`

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
UPDATE Employee
SET Department = (
  SELECT AID
 FROM Department
 WHERE AID = Department AND Employee.Name = 'Excellent Employee')
WHERE Name = 'Good Employee' LIMIT 1;
```

(The statement above doesn't work)

Comment: Why statement above is not working?

Comment: There is a problem with the foreign key

Comment: @Zois I see that you selected Goat's answer while I was typing mine. That's great, but I would really appreciate it if you would take a few minutes to read mine to get a better understanding of what you're doing. Please don't change your vote as Goat deserved his vote, but just take a read. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you've got going on, but here is basic syntax for updating with a join in MySQL:

```
UPDATE FROM EmployeeAS e
 LEFT JOIN Department as dept
 ON e.? = dept.?
   AND e.Name = 'Good Employee' 
 SET e.Department = dept.AID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible. You're off to a pretty good start. The parts that are correct are:

- You are updating `Employee` where `Name='Good Employee'`
- You are selecting a `Department`'s `AID`.

From your query, it looks like the "works_at" relationship is stored in the `Employee` table under the column `Department`.
I can't tell how you are modeling the "runs" relationship. Let's just assume an `Employee` who runs a `Department` must also work at that department. Hence, we can just find which department "Excellent Employee" works at.

To find the department Excellent works at, we can use this query:

```
SELECT Department FROM Employee WHERE Name = 'Excellent Employee'
```

Thus, to move Good to Excellent's department, we can put that into the UPDATE:

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET Department = (
    ...
) WHERE Name = 'Good Employee'
```

Unfortunately, MySQL has some quirks, so we need to change our subquery to work around that:

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET Department = (
    SELECT X.Department FROM (SELECT * FROM Employee) as X WHERE X.Name = 'Excellent Employee'
) WHERE Name = 'Good Employee'
```

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b68bb/2

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, problem with this is (if im not mistaken) the 1:1 relation between Employee and Department with the runs relationship.

Comment: @Zois Yes, the 1:1 relationship between Employee and Department is probably in the Department table. I just assumed that the employee that runs the department also works at that department.